# useEffect hook re-rendering twice in React & Socket.io

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, socket.io, react-router

I'm in the process of building a real-time chat app using React and socket to get to grips with the basics. Whenever a user sends a message, all other users receive this same message twice.

I'm using react-router to serve a join 'page' and a chat 'page'.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">

      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Join />} />
          <Route path="/chat/:name" element={<Chat />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>

    </div>
  );
}
```

In the chat page, which is where the messages are being rendered between users, I'm using the `useEffect` hook however I am struggling to fully understand it.

```
function Chat () {
  const [messages, addMessage] = useState([{
    username: "chatbot",
    time: new Date(),
    message: "Welcome to the chatroom "
  }]);

  const location = useLocation();
  const [currentUser, updateUser] = useState(() => {
    const user = location.pathname.split('/chat/')[1];
    socket.emit("join_chat", {
      username: user
    })
    return user;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("receive_message", (data) => {
      console.log('received message');
      addMessage(prevMessages => {
        return [...prevMessages, {
          username: data.username,
          time: new Date(),
          message: data.message
        }]
      })
    })
  }, [socket])

  const sendMessage = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    socket.emit("send_message", {
      message: currentMessage,
      username: currentUser,
    });
```

The console log is run twice on the receiving side every time a message is sent.

From what I understand, the hook allows us to define some code that will be run whenever there is a change to the DOM, so I'm unsure where this change is happening twice?

I'm also unsure as to why the `socket.on` should live inside `useEffect` in the first place. If `useEffect` is only called immediately after a re-render, how is it still receiving every message via the socket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you describe it sounds like you are rendering the app into a `React.StrictMode` component which runs certain lifecycle methods and functions twice as a way to help detect unintentional/unexpected side-effects.

The effect is run twice and the unintentional/unexpected side-effect is that the code has added ***two*** event handlers for the `"receive_message"` event.

The `useEffect` hook is missing returning a cleanup function to unsubscribe from the socket/message event when the component unmounts or the `socket` dependency changes.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const handleMessage = (data) => {
    console.log('received message');
    addMessage(prevMessages => {
      return [...prevMessages, {
        username: data.username,
        time: new Date(),
        message: data.message
      }]
    });
  };

  socket.on("receive_message", handleMessage);

  return () => {
    socket.off("receive_message", handleMessage);
  };
}, [socket]);
```

> From what I understand, the hook allows us to define some code that
> will be run whenever there is a change to the DOM

The `useEffect` hook allows you to define some code that will run as a side-effect whenever the component renders for any reason. Reasons React components rerender are (1) Local state was updated, (2) a React prop was updated, (3) the parent component rerendered (*for any of the same reasons*).

> I'm also unsure as to why the `socket.on` should live inside `useEffect`
> in the first place.

The "render" method in React components is to be considered a pure function. The ***entire*** function body of a React Function component ***is*** the "render" method. Subscribing to external resources is considered an "impure" action, i.e. it's a side-effect, and should only be subscribed to as part of the regular React component lifecycle.